# Displaying error message and redirecting from the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

**Current Status: Not Solved**

---

I'm just looking to show an error message to see if the user email already exists. For that, I have `checkValidUser` function which returns the responses back. Now, I am accessing those responses as `message` in `RegistrationForm` component.

For now I'm able to console the message here in the component, as seen below.

So, the flow is like:

When the user enters the email, if email is already there in the database, a toastError should be shown saying "User already exists". If the email is not present in the db, a toastSuccess should be showing saying "You are succesfully registered", and at the same time redirected to the login page.

I'm not able to figure out how to accomplish this.

**RegistrationForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { registerUser, checkValidUser } from "../actions/userActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import validator from "validator";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { toastError, toastInfo, toastSuccess } from "../../utils/toastify";

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(" inside componentDidUpdate");
    console.log("cdu", "prevProp=>", prevProps.message, "newProp=>", this.props.message);
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { username, email, password } = this.state;

    const registrationData = {
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      return toastError("Credentials should not be empty");
    }

    if (username.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Username should be greater than 6 characters.");
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      return toastError("Invalid email.");
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Password must contain 6 characters.");
    }

    await this.props.dispatch(checkValidUser(email));

    const message = this.props.message;
    console.log("message in component=>", message)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    const isRegistrationInProgress = this.props.isRegistrationInProgress;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              className="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              className="input"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              className="input"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            {isRegistrationInProgress ? (
              <button className="button is-success is-loading">Sign Up</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
                Sign up
              </button>
            )}
            <Link to="/login">
              <p className="has-text-danger">
                Already have an account? Sign In
              </p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isRegistrationInProgress: state.registration.isRegistrationInProgress,
    message: state.registration.message,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RegistrationForm);
```

**registerUser** action

```
export const registerUser = (registrationData, redirect) => {
    console.log("registrationData", registrationData)
    return async (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: "REGISTRATION_STARTS" })
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          `${baseUrl}/users/register`,
          registrationData
        )
        dispatch({
          type: "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS",
          data: { user: res.data.user },
        })
        toastSuccess("Successfully registered")
        redirect()
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
          type: "REGISTRATION_ERROR",
          data: { error: err },
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**checkValidUser** controller function

```js
checkValidUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside check valid user controller")
    const { email } = req.params
    console.log(email)
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (user) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "User already exists" })
      } else {
        return res.json({ message: "User does not exists" })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

**registerUser** controller function:

```js
registerUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      var { username, email, password } = req.body
      if (password) {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
      }
      if (!username || !email || !password) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
      }
      if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
      }
      if (password.length < 6) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
      }
      const user = await User.create({ username, email, password })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No user found " })
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ user })
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

**registration reducer**

```js
const initialState = {
  isRegistrationInProgress: false,
  isRegistered: false,
  registrationError: null,
  user: {},
  isValidating: false,
  isValidated: false,
  validationError: null,
  message: "",
}

const registration = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REGISTRATION_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: true,
        registrationError: null,
      }

    case "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: null,
        isRegistered: true,
        user: action.data,
      }

    case "REGISTRATION_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: action.data.error,
        isRegistered: false,
        user: {},
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isValidating: true,
        isValidated: false,
        validationError: null,
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isValidating: false,
        isValidated: true,
        message: action.data.message,
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        validationError: action.data.error,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default registration
```

**checkValidUser** action

```js
export const checkValidUser = (email) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/checkValidUser/${email}`)
      console.log("message in action=>", res.data)
      dispatch({
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_SUCCESS",
        data: { message: res.data.message },
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_ERROR",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the  complete link to the github project. That way, it will be easier to visualize. I am seeing where your dispatcher is calling a backend API method.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling registerUser?

Comment: @tksilicon yes, but before that, I have to check if the email is valid is not. So, `checkValidUser` is there. Yes, I need to call `registerUser`.

Comment: I'm confused whether to show error message in componentDidUpdate and redirect from there.

Comment: Where is your reducer? Where is your  checkValidUser action that calls the controller? You posted registerUser twice.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated just now with backend `registerUser` controller and `registration` reducer function.

Comment: Here calling checkValidUsre:

`await this.props.dispatch(checkValidUser(email))`

Comment: Move this to chat

Comment: If you want to show error message, you have to dispatch an action that calls the checkValidUser API first to return the appropriate response. If you don't call the API, how will you know, that is what I put in that answer and you said it wasn't helpful and I have to delete it.

Comment: I am dispatching an action. I think you didn't see that. Check my comment above.
`await this.props.dispatch(checkValidUser(email))`

Comment: really sorry. i just added that part. its updated now.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapStateToProps since your component needs the isValidated current state when email action is dispatched:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
          return {
            isRegistrationInProgress: state.registration.isRegistrationInProgress,
            message: state.registration.message,
           isValidated: state.checkValidUser.isValidated
          };
        };
```

You should check your response message after dispatching in your checkValidUser action. Because the response would be 200 if call succeeds but it doesn’t mean validated could be email exists or not.

```
export const checkValidUser = (email) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/checkValidUser/${email}`)
      console.log("message in action=>", res.data)

      if(res.data.messsage="User does not exists"){//you can just return 
          dispatch({                                 // success or failed
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_SUCCESS",
        data: { message: res.data.message },
      })
       toastSuccess("Success");
      redirect();
      }else{
       toastError("Email exists")
     }

    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_ERROR",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what about the backend responses, and redirect on successful registration?

Comment: Idk but `this.props.isValidated` is always true, whether wrong or correct email address is entered.

Comment: You should check your response message after dispatching in your checkvalidemail action. Because the response would be 200 if call succeeds but it doesn’t mean validated could be email exists or not. That would be what you use to dispatch success or failed. Then that’s what you should also use to redirect()